# How can I change the vector of a ball in breakout game made using Java?

Tags: java, angle, breakout

I'm using Java to make a breakout game. The independent parts are functioning: the paddle, the ball, the bricks.

However, the ball hits a wall and then instead of changing it's vector, the ball just travels up the x-axis in a straight line at the edge of the JFrame window until it hits the top of the window and bounces back down from this corner.

The ball then gets stuck in an infinite back and forth line from the top left corner until it touches the paddle (back and forth) and will never break any of the other bricks.

How can I change my code to fix this problem?

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    public class Ball extends Sprite {

    private int xVelocity = 1, yVelocity = -1;

    // Constructor
    public Ball() {
        setWidth(Settings.BALL_WIDTH);
        setHeight(Settings.BALL_HEIGHT);
        resetPosition();

    public void resetPosition() {
        setX(Settings.INITIAL_BALL_X);
        setY(Settings.INITIAL_BALL_Y);
    }

    public void update() {
        x += yVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;

        // Bounce off left side of screen
        if(x <= 0) {
            x = 0;
            setXVelocity(-1);

        }

        // Bounce off right side of screen
        if(x >= Settings.WINDOW_WIDTH - Settings.BALL_WIDTH) {
            x =Settings.WINDOW_WIDTH;
            setXVelocity(-1);
        }

        // Bounce off top of screen
        if(y <= 0) {
            y = 0;
            setYVelocity(1);
        }

    }

    public void setXVelocity(int x) {
        xVelocity = x;
    }
    public void setYVelocity(int y) {
        yVelocity = y;
    }

    public int getXVelocity() {
        return xVelocity;   
    }
    public int getYVelocity() {
        return yVelocity;   
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, Settings.BALL_WIDTH, Settings.BALL_HEIGHT);
    }
}



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BreakoutPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private boolean gameRunning = true;
    private int livesLeft = 3;
    private String screenMessage = "";
    private Ball ball;
    private Paddle paddle;
    private Brick bricks[];

    public BreakoutPanel(Breakout game) {

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
        timer.start();

        ball = new Ball();
        paddle = new Paddle();
        bricks = new Brick[Settings.TOTAL_BRICKS];
        createBricks();

    }

    private void createBricks() {
        int counter = 0;
        int x_space = 0;
        int y_space = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                bricks[counter] = new Brick((x * Settings.BRICK_WIDTH) + Settings.BRICK_HORI_PADDING + x_space, (y * Settings.BRICK_HEIGHT) + Settings.BRICK_VERT_PADDING + y_space);
                counter++;
                y_space++;
            }
            x_space++;
            y_space = 0;
        }
    }

    private void paintBricks(Graphics g) {
        for(int x = 0; x < Settings.TOTAL_BRICKS; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < Settings.TOTAL_BRICKS; y++) {
                bricks[y].paint(g);
            }
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        if(gameRunning) {
            // TODO: Update the ball and paddle
            ball.update();
            paddle.update();
            collisions();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private void gameOver() {
        stopGame();
        screenMessage = "Game Over!";
    }

    private void gameWon() {
        stopGame();
        screenMessage = "Congratulations! You have won!";
    }

    private void stopGame() {
        gameRunning = false;
    }

    private void collisions() {
        // Check for loss
        if(ball.y > 450) {
            // Game over
            livesLeft--;
            if(livesLeft <= 0) {
                gameOver();
                return;
            } else {
                ball.resetPosition();
                ball.setYVelocity(-1);
            }
        }

        // Check for win
        boolean bricksLeft = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
            // Check if there are any bricks left
            if(!bricks[i].isBroken()) {
                // Brick was found, close loop
                bricksLeft = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!bricksLeft) {
            gameWon();
            return;
        }

        // Check collisions
        if(ball.getRectangle().intersects(paddle.getRectangle())) {
            // Simplified touching of paddle
            ball.setYVelocity(-1);

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
            if (ball.getRectangle().intersects(bricks[i].getRectangle())) {
                int ballLeft = (int) ball.getRectangle().getMinX();
                int ballHeight = (int) ball.getRectangle().getHeight();
                int ballWidth = (int) ball.getRectangle().getWidth();
                int ballTop = (int) ball.getRectangle().getMinY();

                Point pointRight = new Point(ballLeft + ballWidth + 1, ballTop);
                Point pointLeft = new Point(ballLeft - 1, ballTop);
                Point pointTop = new Point(ballLeft, ballTop - 1);
                Point pointBottom = new Point(ballLeft, ballTop + ballHeight + 1);

                if (!bricks[i].isBroken()) {
                    if (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pointRight)) {
                        ball.setXVelocity(-1);
                    } else if (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pointLeft)) {
                        ball.setXVelocity(1);
                    }

                    if (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pointTop)) {
                        ball.setYVelocity(1);
                    } else if (bricks[i].getRectangle().contains(pointBottom)) {
                        ball.setYVelocity(-1);
                    }
                    bricks[i].setBroken(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        ball.paint(g);
        paddle.paint(g);
        paintBricks(g);

        // Draw lives left
        // TODO: Draw lives left in the top left hand corner**
        if(livesLeft != 0) {
            String displayLives = Integer.toString(livesLeft);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            g.drawString(displayLives, Settings.LIVES_POSITION_X, Settings.LIVES_POSITION_Y);
        }

        // Draw screen message*
        if(screenMessage != null) {
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            int messageWidth = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(screenMessage);
            g.drawString(screenMessage, (Settings.WINDOW_WIDTH / 2) - (messageWidth / 2), 
     Settings.MESSAGE_POSITION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            paddle.setXVelocity(-1);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        paddle.setXVelocity(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            paddle.setXVelocity(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        update();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar game in python years ago. What I did to solve this problem was allow the player to control the direction of the ball by hitting it with different parts of the paddle.

If the player hit the ball with the absolute center of the paddle, then I would just reverse the vector as if it had hit off a wall. But if the absolute edge of the paddle hit the ball, then I would increase the x velocity in the same direction of the edge that it hit. You can make the effect continuous, so if the the ball hits the paddle halfway between the edge and the center, it increases the x velocity half as much as it would have if it had hit the absolute edge.

This way the vector will continuously change and the ball will bounce off of things in a more interesting way, as well as give the player more control so they don't have to just wait until the ball eventually hits every brick in a predefined pattern.

You can use a coefficient, or more complex function if you don't want the effect of where the ball hits the paddle to effect the x velocity in such a linear manner.

You can use a similar strategy for handling collisions with the bricks. For instance, if the ball hits the corner of a brick, you probably don't want it to react as if it had hit the bottom, or the side, but have a reaction that is somewhere in between.